# I need to connect with an instance which is created in a VMware based eucalyptus cloud platform but i don't understand how to do it?

Tags: eucalyptus

Connect to instance: i-38942195
To connect to your instance, be sure security group my-test-security-group has TCP port 22 open to inbound traffic and then perform the following steps (these instructions do not apply if you did not select a key pair when you launched this instance):

Open an SSH terminal window.
Change your directory to the one where you stored your key file my-test-keypair.pem
Run the following command to set the correct permissions for your key file:
chmod 400 my-test-keypair.pem
Connect to your instance via its public IP address by running the following command:
ssh -i my-test-keypair.pem root@192.168.0.29

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus no longer supports VMware, but to generally troubleshoot instance connectivity you would first check that you are using a known good image such as those available via:

```
# python <(curl -Ls https://eucalyptus.cloud/images)
```

and ensure that the instance booted correctly:

```
# euca-get-console-output i-38942195
```

if that looks good (check for instance meta-data access for the SSH key) then check that the security group rules are correct, and that the instance is running using the expected security group and SSH key.

VMWare deprecation notice from version 4.1:

> Support for VMWare features in Eucalyptus has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

http://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#release-notes/4.1.0/4.1.0_rn_features.html

Euca2ools command:

http://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#euca2ools-guide/euca-get-console-output.html